# Using a loop to create a polynomial model gives R trouble understanding it?

Tags: r

I create a lot of polynomial models to compare them, so I used a loop like this:

```
library(ISLR)
library(boot)
data(Wage)

list = list()
for (i in 1:10){
  list[[i]] = lm(wage ~ poly(age, i), data = Wage)
  assign(paste("fit.aov", i, sep = ""), list[[i]])
  
}

agelims <- range(Wage$age)
age.grid <- seq(agelims[1], agelims[2])
```

If I run the following code

```
preds <- predict(fit.aov1, data.frame(age = age.grid), se=TRUE)
```

I receive the following error:

> Error: variable 'poly(age, i)' was fitted with type "nmatrix.1" but type "nmatrix.10" was supplied
> In addition: Warning message:
> In Z/rep(sqrt(norm2[-1L]), each = length(x)) :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

However, if I create each model manually like this

```
fit1  = lm(wage, poly(age,1), data = Wage)
```

Then the predict() function runs just fine.

Comment: How do I do that? Also, I do not understand why the error emerged. I don't see how the two approaches are fundamentally different.

Comment: oh, dang it. Is it not advisable to use a loop to generate models, then?

Comment: That is not the case.  It is just that som models you are matching with the call and other things

Comment: @akrun thanks a lot!

Comment: There is an issue in your code which i overlooked earlier.  Please check my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we need to create the `formula` with `paste`

```
lst1 <- vector('list', 10)
for (i in 1:10){
  fmla <- sprintf("wage~ poly(age,%d)", i)
  print(fmla)
  lst1[[i]] = lm(as.formula(fmla), data = Wage)
  lst1[[i]]$call <- parse(text =fmla )[[1]]

  assign(paste("fit.aov", i, sep = ""), lst1[[i]])
  
}
```

-testing with `predict`

```
predict(fit.aov1, data.frame(age = age.grid), se=TRUE)
#$fit
#        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13        14 
# 94.43570  95.14298  95.85025  96.55753  97.26481  97.97208  98.67936  99.38663 100.09391 100.80119 101.50846 102.21574 102.92301 103.63029 
#       15        16        17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24        25        26        27        28 
#104.33757 105.04484 105.75212 106.45939 107.16667 107.87394 108.58122 109.28850 109.99577 110.70305 111.41032 112.11760 112.82488 113.53215 
#       29        30        31        32        33        34        35        36        37        38        39        40        41        42 
#114.23943 114.94670 115.65398 116.36126 117.06853 117.77581 118.48308 119.19036 119.89764 120.60491 121.31219 122.01946 122.72674 123.43402 
#       43        44        45        46        47        48        49        50        51        52        53        54        55        56 
#124.14129 124.84857 125.55584 126.26312 126.97039 127.67767 128.38495 129.09222 129.79950 130.50677 131.21405 131.92133 132.62860 133.33588 
#       57        58        59        60        61        62        63 
#134.04315 134.75043 135.45771 136.16498 136.87226 137.57953 138.28681 
# ...
```

---

The issue was that we are passing `poly(age, i)` which is not getting recognized as `1`, `2`, ... instead as only `i`